# Convert string with format 12 hour(04/29/2013 10:00:00 AM) to datetime in C#

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, datetime, service

I'm retrieving a string like this (04/29/2013 10:00:00 AM) from my config.xml.I want to convert this to DateTime format.How to do this?

I tried followings:

```
DateTime dtNextrunTimeforExcel = Convert.ToDateTime(str);
```

and

```
DateTime dtNextrunTimeforExcel = DateTime.Parse(str);
```

But, in both the case its saying "string was not recognized as a valid datetime".

Note:I'm writing Windows service with VS2010

Pl. help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.ParseExact`

```
var dtNextrunTimeforExcel = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: I have modified my question.Once, I will get date time, I will compare this with current date time.So, will Var work?

Comment: @bapirout - it will return a DateTime.  var is strongly typed and is the equivalent of `DateTime dtNextrunTimeforExcel` in this case. So it will work.

Comment: You have not considered AM/PM...If I use AM/PM, I'm getting same error.

Comment: @bapirout - So just adjust include the AM/PM in the parse string.

Answer (score 2):

```
 CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US"); 
 string dateString;
 DateTime dateValue;

 // Parse a string.
 dateString = "4/29/2013 10:00:00 AM"; 
 if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", enUS, 
                    DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
  Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, dateValue, 
                 dateValue.Kind);

  ///time only
  dateString = "10:00:00 AM"; 
 if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "hh:mm:ss tt", enUS, 
                    DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
  Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, dateValue, 
                 dateValue.Kind);
```