# Convert String "7/16/2013 7:00:00 AM" to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net

I am shoked why its giving me an error

```
Convert.ToDateTime("7/16/2013 7:00:00 AM");
```

but works fine if i use

```
Convert.ToDateTime(("16/7/2013 7:00:00 AM");
```

How can i convert "7/16/2013 7:00:00 AM" to `DateTime`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string with format 12 hour(04/29/2013 10:00:00 AM) to datetime in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281975/convert-string-with-format-12-hour04-29-2013-100000-am-to-datetime-in-c-shar)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either use a specific locale or you can define the [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4.aspx) by yourself like this:

```
 var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("7/16/2013 7:00:00 AM", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I have used

- M Month 0-12 number without leading zeros
- d Day number 0-31 without leading zeros
- yyyy Year with all digits
- M Hour in 12h format 0-12 without leading zeros
- mm Minutes 0-59 with leading zeros
- ss Seconds 0-59 with leading zeros

As culture I did specify invariant culture which is basically English on all systems. It is the same regardless of the current culture of the system or the thread.

Your problem did arrise from the fact that you did try to process dates from different locales with the same thread locale from your system which seems to be English. To correctly treat the dates you need to know in which locale it was entered to be able to correctly parse it. Some locales do switch e.g. month and days as it was in your example. Some use different separaters and even other cultures have different uses for the . , chars as thousand separators and decimal point.

German uses , as decimal point and . as thousand separator. A date would look like

"24.12.2013 14:25:59"

No AM/PM no / but many dots.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be aware about the culture, refer to this link : [Convert.ToDateTime Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t.aspx)

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

Convert.ToDateTime("7/16/2013 7:00:00 AM", culture );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it still giving the same error. and thanks for the links also. it seems to be very basic which i didn't know after two years of experience.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply try to use `DateTime.TryParse()`

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParse("7/16/2013 7:00:00 AM", out dt))
    Console.Write(dt);
```